# Facebook AppLink created from applinkshost

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller, applinks

I use UIActivityViewController for sharing content, code is pretty simple:

```
  UIActivityViewController* activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:[feedCell activityItems]
                                                                                     applicationActivities:nil];
  [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

where activityItems are:

```
- (NSArray *)activityItems {
  return @[self.titleLabel.text, self.titleImageView.image, [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.m..234"]];
}
```

Can't figure out, is it possible to make an app link created from Facebook 
[App Links Hosting API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api) has an thumb + install/open button?

I created one and it works great, but it has only a title and fb.me..:

[image]

My goal is to make it look like this:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that does not seem to be possible. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/app-link-host lists the fields an app link host object has – and there is no thumbnail.

If you want a thumbnail, then you have to add the App Links meta data to an existing URL: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content With that, you can use all the other OG meta tags as well.

Comment: hi, tnx for the answer, I created a test url with meta tags, I tested it with uiactivityviewcontroller and it works fine: displays an image, title and description. But now it is a problem to attach an image, I read lots of posts and it seems like this is a well known problem, I tried to to make a post via slcomposerviewcontroller, fbsdksharedialog and as I wrote before uiactivityviewcontroller, but result is the same - if a attach an fb app link as a url, then there is no image in feed post..I would be grateful to if you have any ideas about it. Thanks anyway)

Comment: I attached an image via meta tags, it is an icon of an app, but I need to attach one more as a post with description